# Android Fragment Clear back stack in FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter, fragment-backstack

I am using `FragmentPagerAdapter` having three tabs each tab is having its own Root Fragment (each with its own `FrameLayout`). This Root `Fragment` is used as a place holder for other `Fragments`.What i am trying to achieve is that whenever the tab is switched `Fragment` Back Stack should be cleared.
Here's is `adapter` code.

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        MainScreen mActivity = (MainScreen)mContext;
        FragmentManager manager = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (manager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            FragmentManager.BackStackEntry first = manager.getBackStackEntryAt(0);
            manager.popBackStack(first.getId(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        }

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new BaseFragment();
            case 1:
                return new BaseActivityFragment();
            case 2:
                return new BaseSalesFragment();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: use setMenuVisibility(boolean isVisible) method in your fragments. and if the fragment is visible then using interface concept of passing data from fragment to activity, clear your backstack in activity

Comment: do you want to remove BaseFragment when you switch to BaseActivityFragment with tabs?

Comment: No Basically Each Tab is having its own Place holder Fragment that is supposed to be replaced by the child fragment of each tab.i want to clear the back stack (if there is any) whenever a tab is clicked.leaving behind the base fragment that actually add another fragment inside its onCreatView() method

Answer (score 1):

Solved thanks for the participation.it did the trick.

```
pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            FragmentManager manager = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
            if (manager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                while (manager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
                    manager.popBackStackImmediate();
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```